# Protractor, when should I use then() after a click()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automated-tests, protractor

I'm running an Angular app and when testing on protractor a `click()`, I don't know when should I resolve the promise with a `then()`.

I found this on Protractor API:

> A promise that will be resolved when the click command has completed.

So, should I use `click().then()` in every `click`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> So, should I use click().then() in every click?

Definitely not.

It's not needed because Protractor/WebDriverJS has this mechanism called ["Control Flow"](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) which is basically a queue of promises that need to be resolved:

> WebDriverJS maintains a queue of pending promises, called the control
>   flow, to keep execution organized.

and Protractor waits for Angular naturally and out-of-the-box:

> You no longer need to add waits and sleeps to your test. Protractor
>   can automatically execute the next step in your test the moment the
>   webpage finishes pending tasks, so you don’t have to worry about
>   waiting for your test and webpage to sync.

Which leads to a quite straight-forward testing code:

```
var elementToBePresent = element(by.css(".anotherelementclass")).isPresent();

expect(elementToBePresent.isPresent()).toBe(false);
element(by.css("#mybutton")).click();
expect(elementToBePresent.isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

---

Sometimes though, if you experience synchronization/timing issues, or your app under test is non-Angular, you may solve it by resolving the `click()` explicitly with `then()` and continue inside the click callback:

```
expect(elementToBePresent.isPresent()).toBe(false);
element(by.css("#mybutton")).click().then(function () {
    expect(elementToBePresent.isPresent()).toBe(true);
});
```

There are also [Explicit Waits](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) to the rescue in these cases, but it's not relevant here.

Comment: The future of Control Flow is in question.
"In the future, the control flow is being removed"
[The WebDriver Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md#disabling-the-control-flow)

Comment: If some future version of protractor removes control flow, my company **won't use it**. Seriously we'd have to rewrite all our testcases! it would be a nightmare!

Comment: @JohnHenckel I hear you, we had like 40k lines of protractor tests, imagine rewriting that :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should.
Maybe right now it's not necessary, but maybe in next versions it is.
So, if `click` return a promise, you should use it.

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.click

Comment: The future of Control Flow is in question.
"In the future, the control flow is being removed"
[The WebDriver Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md#disabling-the-control-flow)