# Does Protractor have IE 9 browser compatibility?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, selenium, protractor

I have to write end-to-end acceptance tests for my Angular App which runs on IE9. I want to know is the browser simulated by Protractor equivalent to IE9 or above?

Answer (score 1):

In the ideal world or looking on it through the "rose-coloured glasses":

> Yes, sure. Write your tests once - reuse and execute multiple times on any browser/capability out there. It's all handled by the same Selenium/WebDriverJS/Protractor API.

In the real world, it's not that simple. With Internet Explorer, it often comes to something you need to handle in a special way, add something to your testing code so that your expectations would be met: [explicitly resolve a click promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33441331/protractor-when-should-i-use-then-after-a-click/33441392#33441392), or add an [explicit wait](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait), or add an artificial delay, or turn off angular animations, increase [implicit wait timeouts](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.Timeouts.prototype.implicitlyWait) - you name it.